# Linear equation solving with special sparse coefficient matrix

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, linear-algebra, numerical-algorithms

Given a linear equation system of $n$ equations with unknowns $a_1,a_2,...,a_n\in [0,1]$, where the left hand side of each equation consists of not more than $k$ variables (so there are at least $n-k$ zero terms in each matrix row), what is the fastest way (in terms of time complexity) to solve such a system.

I know that simple equation-by-equation reduction will result in $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ if I'm not mistaken. But is there a faster way of solving it (ideally linear in $n$, e.g. $\mathcal{O}(kn)$)? Because I'm new to the subject of computational linear algebra I have no idea wether or not this is possible.

EDIT: I should also say that either the coefficients in an equation are all the same and add up to zero (so they basically describe an arithmetic mean, for example $\frac{1}{2}a_1+\frac{1}{2}a_2-a_3=0$) OR the equation consists of a single variable and a value (e.g. $a_5=1$).

Comment: A general bound for $n$ variables makes little sense here, you'd have to tell how many "equations are a single variable" (they can be used in one sweep to cut down the size of the system) and how many *non-zero* coefficients remain.

Comment: The number single-variable-equations can be arbitrarily small, so assume the worst case of only $1$ of this kind. The number of non zero coefficients are therefore in $\mathcal{O}(kn)$. I should also say that I would strongly prefer direct algorithms instead of iterative approximations.

Answer (score 3):

There are iterative methods in which each iteration takes time $O(nnz)$, where $nnz$ is the number of non-zero entries. See for example Chapter 4 of [Saad's lecture notes](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cme324/saad.pdf). For the state-of-the-art, consult Section 5 of [Lee and Sidford (2013)](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.1922v1.pdf). For special types of matrices, see [Lee, Peng and Spielman (2016)](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.08204v2.pdf).

Comment: @DavidRicherby $nnz$ is standard notation, after the matlab function. It appears in papers of Lee and Sidford.

Comment: Oh, OK. Man, that's _terrible_ notation.